# Yii deletes child record after parent save

Tags: php, yii

I have a Yii project (with activerecord-relation-behavior), where I create an Order record, and I add some connected product's to it . Until this point, everything works fine, but I added a feature, to handle the shipping price and add a product, based on the other products weight and Yii creates and immediately deletes that new record.

First version:

```
$new = new Order;
$new->save();
foreach (explode('-', $order['products']) as $product) {
  $op = new OrderProduct();
  $op->order = $new;
  $op->save();
}
$new->save();
```

New version:

```
$new = new Order;
$new->save();
foreach (explode('-', $order['products']) as $product) {
  $op = new OrderProduct();
  $op->order = $new;
  $op->save();
}
$new->save();
$new->update();

$op = new OrderProduct(); // shipment record
$op->order = $new;
$op->save(); //until this point, this works until I add the next line

$new->save(); // This deletes the new record.
```

beforeSave() in the Order class:

```
public function beforeSave(){
    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($this->items as $op) {
        $sum += ($op->unit_price + $op->unit_price * ($op->vat / 100)) * $op->quantity;
    }

    $this->final_cost = $sum;
    return true;
}
```

I don't know why, but the last line deletes the new record.

I need to save the total cost into the Order, so I have to save it anyway. Now I have a `beforeSave()` method, that calculates all of the OrderProduct-s, get the sum of all prices and save it to the Order.

What could be wrong with my code, why is Yii deleting my new record?

Comment: so post your beforeSave()

Comment: I tried it up and it worked fine. What record was deleted? $new (Order) or OrderProduct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed your step but I couln't duplicate issue. The record has not been deleted.
Let's see my example.

```
$new = new Order;
        $new->label = 'order 1';
        $new->save(false);

        $op = new OrderProduct();
        $op->label = '1st op';
        $op->order = $new;
        $op->save(false);

        $new->save(false);
        $new->update(false);

        $op = new OrderProduct(); 
        $op->label '2nd op';
        $op->order= $new;
        $op->save(false); 

        $new->save();

//Until now, I have 1 record Order and 2 Order Products, nothing has been removed.
```

I don't use beforeSave, but if there was something wrong with your one, eventually the new record should have to be created even, but not in your case because you said that it has been created and removed after then.

I posted this answer to post the copy code which workied on my side, and I think there has more stuff that you did not post here, maybe it just caused your problem

Comment: Thanks for the help, I can't copy my whole code here, because 1: it's  400 lines, 2: it belongs to the company I work for.
Now I found a workaround by loading the Order into another variable, by the original's id, and somehow it works :)